# Inconsistent fractional exponents in python

Tags: python, complex-numbers, exponent

Please could anyone explain in the below example why the one gets a different answer if depending on whether the number being raised is input directly vs input as a variable?:

```
>>>print(-2**(1/0.33))
-8.169812850522913

>>>x=-2
>>>print(x**(1/0.33))
(-8.132819305372337-0.7765900841063754j)
```

Inn addition I'd be very grateful if anyone could explain how to get the first answer but using the second approach

Answer (score 2):

Because of [operator precedence](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Evalerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) (`**` has a higher precedence than the *unary* `-`), your first expression is being evaluated as:

```
-(2**(1/0.33))
# -8.169812850522913
```

Whereas in the second case, since you've already defined `-2` as a variable, it is evaluated as:

```
(-2)**(1/0.33)
# (-8.132819305372337-0.7765900841063753j)
```

Which happens to result in a complex number.

Comment: It's kind of the same, but shouldn't it be "is being evaluated as `-(2**...)`"? Also, you might write "higher precedence than _unary_ `-`", since unary minus has e.g. higher precedence than multiplication, but still lower than exponentiation.

Comment: I guess it was just to exemplify that the neg factor `(*(-1))` was evaluated after @tobias_k

Comment: Yes, that's indeed an important detail @tobias_k added

Answer (score 1):

The first case, only the 2 has the exponent, the second case it's '-2'.
`(-2)**(1/0.33)` should give the second result